# Vuex | Map state - Scoping issue in beforeMount() on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm having a scoping issues with Vuex mapState. I have a requirement to output the users name locally on the page without it being reactively updated by v-model in my input field (for the same user's name data).

The following code works fine, however if the user refreshes the page the state is lost and returns as undefined.

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(["userProfile"]),
},

beforeMount() {
  this.localUserProfile.name = this.userProfile.name;
  console.log("localUserProfile: " + this.localUserProfile.name); 
},
```

Comment: You should store vuex state in localStorage (or sessionStorage) in case you want to keep it after page refreshing. You may use `vuex-persistedstate` or similar plugins

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be happening is that your `userProfile` data in Vuex is set only after the component has mounted when you directly refresh the page? In that case `userProfile.name` might still be undefined when you assign it. If this is what happens, you could add a watcher in this component that checks for changes in the `userProfile` and updates the `localProfile` if it hasn't been set during the mount.

Also: have you looked at the v-once directive? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once
This should prevent the username from being updated when the value changes without having to reference a local copy.